Flutter 3.24.3 dart:js_interop (not using soon to be deprecated "js" package) access data from a StatefulWidget example
Hopefully, the Dart docs for latest dart:js_interop functionality will get some more examples soon. Until then, for anyone else looking for some understanding...
The following app will give you the interface in the screenshot. Then, using the current dart:js_interop (not the soon to be deprecated "js" package), when you tap the HTML "Get String" button, the TextFormField's controller "text" value will be retrieved from the StatefulWidget, and set in the HTML innerHtml.

pubspec.yaml
name: testing
description: "Testing Flutter Embedding"

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ^3.5.3

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text_field: ^2.2.4
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.1
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  path_provider: ^2.1.4
  simple_widget_snapshot: ^2.0.0
  uuid: ^4.5.1
  web: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

lib/main.dart (Demonstrates dart:js_interop function exporting and Flutter Element Embedding.)
import 'dart:js_interop';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' show FlutterView;

import 'app/screens/air_force_metal_name_plate_screen.dart';

/// Need to export this Dart function for Javascript globalThis.getTextFieldValue() to access.
/// https://dart.dev/interop/js-interop/usage#export
@JS()
external set getTextFieldValue(JSFunction value);

String getString() {
  return AirForceMetalNamePlateScreenState.text;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  /// Then, in main() we set the exported Dart function that
  /// Javascript can access to the getString() function, which will
  /// access the static "text" value, set by the TextFormField
  /// controller.
  getTextFieldValue = getString.toJS;

  /// Do not display any debugPrint info when in release mode.
  if (kReleaseMode) {
    debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {};
  }

  runWidget(MultiViewApp(
    viewBuilder: (BuildContext context) => const Testing(),
  ));
}

class Testing extends StatelessWidget {
  const Testing({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.white,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const AirForceMetalNamePlateScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MultiViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MultiViewApp({super.key, required this.viewBuilder});

  final WidgetBuilder viewBuilder;

  @override
  State<MultiViewApp> createState() => _MultiViewAppState();
}

/// Required for latest Flutter Element Embedding.
/// https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/embedding-flutter-web
class _MultiViewAppState extends State<MultiViewApp>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _updateViews();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MultiViewApp oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    // Need to re-evaluate the viewBuilder callback for all views.
    _views.clear();
    _updateViews();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    _updateViews();
  }

  Map<Object, Widget> _views = <Object, Widget>{};

  void _updateViews() {
    final Map<Object, Widget> newViews = <Object, Widget>{};
    for (final FlutterView view
        in WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views) {
      final Widget viewWidget = _views[view.viewId] ?? _createViewWidget(view);
      newViews[view.viewId] = viewWidget;
    }
    setState(() {
      _views = newViews;
    });
  }

  Widget _createViewWidget(FlutterView view) {
    return View(
      view: view,
      child: Builder(
        builder: widget.viewBuilder,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewCollection(views: _views.values.toList(growable: false));
  }
}

lib/app/screens/air_force_metal_name_plate_screen.dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:auto_size_text_field/auto_size_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:simple_widget_snapshot/simple_widget_snapshot.dart';

import '../../constants.dart';
import '../../exceptions/usamm_exception.dart';
import '../../helpers/helper_functions.dart';

class AirForceMetalNamePlateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AirForceMetalNamePlateScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AirForceMetalNamePlateScreen> createState() =>
      _AirForceMetalNamePlateScreenState();
}

class _AirForceMetalNamePlateScreenState
    extends State<AirForceMetalNamePlateScreen> {
  double _padding = kIsWeb ? 10 : 2;
  final GlobalKey _snapshotGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _infoFormKey =
      GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: '_airForceMetalNamePlateFormKey');
  final FocusScopeNode _infoFormFocusScope = FocusScopeNode();
  final TextEditingController _infoTextEditingController =
      TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _infoFocusNode = FocusNode();
  String? _snapshot;

  /// Needs to be static for getString() in main.dart to access
  /// the text controller value being set.
  static String text = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _infoTextEditingController.addListener(() {
      text = _infoTextEditingController.text;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _closeKeyboard();
    _infoFormFocusScope.dispose();
    _infoTextEditingController.dispose();
    _infoFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: kAppPadding,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Enter name for your Air Force Metal Nameplate.',
                    style: kDefaultTextStyle,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),

                  /// Background image for the Air Force Metal Nameplate.
                  ///
                  /// And the TextFormField that auto adjusts.
                  RepaintBoundary(
                    key: _snapshotGlobalKey,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 88,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.network(
                            'https://i.ezr.io/_img/nametag-options/nameplate-airforce-metal.jpg?h=96&w=288',
                          ),
                          Form(
                            key: _infoFormKey,
                            child: FocusScope(
                                node: _infoFormFocusScope,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _padding),
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: 240,
                                        child: AutoSizeTextField(
                                          controller:
                                              _infoTextEditingController,
                                          focusNode: _infoFocusNode,
                                          enableSuggestions: false,
                                          autofocus: true,
                                          style: GoogleFonts.dosis(
                                            color: kAirForceMetalNamePlateColor,
                                            fontSize: 45,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            letterSpacing: -1,
                                          ),
                                          maxLines: 1,
                                          maxLength: 20,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          textAlignVertical:
                                              TextAlignVertical.center,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                            hintStyle: GoogleFonts.dosis(
                                              color:
                                                  kAirForceMetalNamePlateColor,
                                              fontSize: 45,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              letterSpacing: -1,
                                            ),
                                            hintText: 'ENTER NAME',
                                            counterText: '',
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                          ),
                                          cursorHeight: 45,
                                          cursorColor: kDefaultRedColor,
                                          cursorWidth: 4,
                                          onChanged: (String? value) {
                                            _adjustPadding();
                                          },
                                          inputFormatters: [
                                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                                RegExp("[a-zA-Z .'-]")),
                                            TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                                              (oldValue, newValue) =>
                                                  TextEditingValue(
                                                text:
                                                    newValue.text.toUpperCase(),
                                                selection: newValue.selection,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  /// For testing purposes only.
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      _closeKeyboard();
                      _snapshot = null;
                      setState(() {});

                      try {
                        final SnapshotResult snapshotResult =
                            await WidgetSnapshot.capture(_snapshotGlobalKey,
                                pixelRatio: 3.0);
                        final Uint8List? pngBytes = snapshotResult.uint8list;

                        if (pngBytes == null) {
                          throw UsammException('Did not capture image.');
                        }
                      } on UsammException catch (e) {
                        if (context.mounted) {
                          HelperFunctions.alert(
                            context: context,
                            title: e.message,
                          );
                        }
                      } on StateError catch (e) {
                        if (context.mounted) {
                          HelperFunctions.alert(
                            context: context,
                            title: e.message,
                          );
                        }
                      } catch (e) {
                        if (context.mounted) {
                          HelperFunctions.alert(
                            context: context,
                            title: e.toString(),
                          );
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Take a picture.'),
                  ),

                  /// Display the snapshot.
                  if (_snapshot != null) ...[
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    Image.file(File(_snapshot!)),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _adjustPadding() {
    if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length == 20) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 24 : 16;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length >= 19) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 23 : 15;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length >= 15) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 21 : 13;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length >= 14) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 18 : 10;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length == 13) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 16 : 8;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length == 12) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 15 : 7;
      setState(() {});
    } else if (_infoTextEditingController.text.length > 11) {
      _padding = kIsWeb ? 14 : 6;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _closeKeyboard() {
    _infoFocusNode.unfocus();
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
  }
}

/web/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flutter & JS Interop</title>
  <style>
    /* Container to hold both the Flutter element and interop section */
    .contents {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 100vh;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    /* Left side - Flutter container */
    article {
      width: 65%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    /* Flutter target div where the Flutter app will be embedded */
    #flutter_target {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #eaeaea;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Right side - JS Interop */
    #demo_controls {
      width: 30%;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* Styling for interop fieldset */
    fieldset {
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
    }

    legend {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    input[type="button"] {
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      background-color: #007bff;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    input[type="button"]:hover {
      background-color: #0056b3;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    /* Text to display the name entered in Flutter */
    #nameDisplay {
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      color: #333;
      /* No border */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<section class="contents">
  <!-- Flutter element embedded on the left side -->
  <article>
    <div id="flutter_target" class="center"></div>
  </article>

  <!-- JS Interop controls -->
  <aside id="demo_controls">
    <fieldset id="interop">
      <legend>JS Web application</legend>
      <!-- Button to trigger JS Interop -->
      <input id="getStringButton" value="Get String" type="button" />

      <!-- Text below the button, initially showing a placeholder -->
      <p id="nameDisplay">Name will show here</p>
    </fieldset>
  </aside>
</section>
<script>
  {{flutter_js}}
  {{flutter_build_config}}

  _flutter.loader.load({
  onEntrypointLoaded: async function onEntrypointLoaded(engineInitializer) {
    let engine = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
      multiViewEnabled: true, // Enables embedded mode.
    });
    const app = await engine.runApp();
    app.addView({
      hostElement: document.querySelector('#flutter_target'),
    });
  }
});
</script>
<script src="js/js-interop.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>

web/js/js-interop.js
// Button click event listener in plain JS
document.getElementById("getStringButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (window.getTextFieldValue) {
    const value = globalThis.getTextFieldValue()
    console.log("Text from Flutter TextField: " + value)
    document.getElementById('nameDisplay').innerHTML = value
  }
})

